# Stored procedure is not working on IIS Server while working fine on localhost in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Can someone help me? I have created method for getting data from a stored procedure in this procedure user select month year and district and it will show numbers of user on that district, it is working fine on localhost but when I upload this to  the server, it is no longer working properly.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult get_Data_with_months(int did, string month, string year)
    {
        string dateset = "01" + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        //string dateset = month + "/01/" + year;
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateset);
        DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
        DateTime lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

       // string second = Did;
        string first = Convert.ToDateTime(firstDayOfMonth).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        string last = Convert.ToDateTime(lastDayOfMonth).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

       var Monthwisetkt = db.spWitnessDataMonthwise(first, last, did).ToList();
        ViewBag.count = Monthwisetkt.Count;

        //Creating table for response data
        StringBuilder DistrictTbl = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 1;
        int j = 0;

        //DistrictTbl.Append("<b>"+ month + year+ "Witness List</b>");
        DistrictTbl.Append("<div class='col-md-12 m-auto'><table class='table table-bordered' id='tbl-data'><thead><tr><th>S.No.</th><th>District Name</th><th>No of  Witness </th></tr></thead><tbody>");
        foreach (var item in Monthwisetkt)
        {
            var DistrictName = Monthwisetkt.ElementAt(j).District_name;
            var no_of_witness = Monthwisetkt.ElementAt(j).NoOfWitness;

            DistrictTbl.Append("<tr><td>"+ count + "</td><td>"+ DistrictName + "</td><td>"+ no_of_witness + "</td></tr>");
            j++;
            count++;
        }
        DistrictTbl.Append("</tbody></table></div>");
        return Json(new { result = "True", msg = DistrictTbl.ToString() });

    }
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spWitnessDataMonthwise] 
     (@fromDate nvarchar(50),  
      @toDate nvarchar(50), 
      @DistrictId int) 
AS 
    SELECT 
        id, District_name, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM WHD_witness 
         WHERE District_Name = dtable.id 
           AND insert_date BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate 
           AND dtable.id = @DistrictId) AS NoOfWitness 
    FROM 
        WHD_district dtable 
    WHERE 
        dtable.id = @DistrictId
```

Comment: Without being able to see ANY code. That would say to me that your db connection string in the application is not correct

Comment: i have added my store procedure and code for fetdching data in admin controller.please help me, thanks.

Comment: I see a big problem with @fromDate and @toDate as `NVARCHAR`. Use date data types for dates.

Comment: thank you for your response i will try this :)

Comment: i tried your code and changed nvarchar to date data type but the result is same it is working fine on local server but not working on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The porblem is that server is taking date in yyyy-mm-dd format so i changed format of my input string which is passing to my function.